# Will ASP CSS page still get cached as normal CSS page?

Tags: asp.net, css, caching

I'm converting a style-sheet from .CSS to .ASPX, so I can load some color configurations from a database, in to my style-sheet.

Inside the aspx style-sheet would be a DB connection, a small SQL query to grab the colors, and then the rest of my css, sometimes containing ASP variables.

Will this styles.aspx page still get cached in the same way as a normal css file would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the URL isn't constantly changing due to a querystring it will be cached just like a normal stylesheet. Browsers only see the response headers sent by the server and the content of the stylesheet, not the source code on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The client does not care at all what happens server side. The only thing it cares about is the response and the response HTTP headers. If those are identical to a regular CSS file, it doesn't make any difference whether the response is served from a file, created dynamically via ASP or written on the fly by unicorns.